# Практическое применение языка OCaml?

Tags: linux, unix, ocaml

Где используется язык OCaml?
Был ли у кого опыт практического применения данного языка.
Благодарю за любую информацию.

Comment: Поиск по гитхабу по запросу `ocaml` показывает 13к репозиториев

Comment: Я встречал ocaml в приложениях по доказательству теорем. Там не только ocaml используется, но и другие языки из семейства ML. Это довольно узкая, но весьма значительная область прикладной логики. Используется для доказательства корректности критического ПО.

Comment: Самое частое применение, которое я встречал — coccinelle для семантического поиска и обновления кода (используется проектом Linux kernel).